# Sendkeys in Appium webview sometimes find element but write nothing

Tags: android, webview, appium

I have some issue sometimes i find the element but the sendkeys that doesn't write anything.

So far that it did append only inside a webview and only on a Samsung S7.

I tried also plenty of times with a Oneplus one (cyanogen os) and I never encountered the issue.

This is how I do it :

1. I'm trying to find my 2 fields (email / password) with WebDriverWait
2. I'm retrieving the objects with driver.findElement(By.id())
3. I'm sending keys to the password
4. I'm sending keys to the email

The step 1 & 2 are working fine even with the Samsung but for some reason, The step 3 works sometimes and sometimes not and then the 4 works fine also every time

Also (and that's the weirdest part) when the sendkeys doesn't work if I print the password.getText() i'm having the correct string so it's there somewhere but not on the screen

Do you have an idea why does this issue happen sometimes with the samsung and never with a oneplus one or how to fix this ?

Answer (score -1):

Add a wait interval :

```
Browser.sleep(10000);
```